# Dependency kills test

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, dependencies

I have a class in maven:

```
src/test/java/StartupTest.java
```

having this code:

```
public class StartupTest {
  public void testStartup(){
    assert false: "Just for fun.";
  }
}
```

If i do a `mvn clean test` it fails like expeted!

```
Failed tests:   StartupTest.testStartup(): Just for fun.
```

### Problem:

If i add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.canoo.webtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>webtest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The test is not executed anymore.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you use JUnit3 or JUnit4?

Comment: I do not used any JUnit. Its solved, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, had to exclude junit

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.canoo.webtest</groupId>
    <artifactId>webtest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```